# load image at the same size as real life, in all platforms

Tags: html, css, image, size, fullscreen

I want to load an image like in real life size, which means the size of the image is 10cm\5cm, so it will stay this size in all platforms,

I tried position absolute and all this stuff, but the size changes in other platforms (same browser..)

**f12 > ctrl+shift+m**, Shows the same size, but in real phone it does not

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert from CM to PX in [here](https://www.unitconverters.net/typography/centimeter-to-pixel-x.htm).

here are the css units :

***em***    Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)
***ex***    Relative to the x-height of the current font (rarely used)
***ch***    Relative to the width of the "0" (zero)
***rem***   Relative to font-size of the root element
***vw***    Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport*
***vh***    Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*
***vmin***  Relative to 1% of viewport's* smaller dimension
***vmax***  Relative to 1% of viewport's* larger dimension
***%***     Relative to the parent element

[more info](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)